# Bluetooth not turning on on Fedora 37 but works on Windows 11

Tags: fedora, bluetooth

## Overview

I have a thinkpad laptop that dual boots to Windows 11 and Fedora 37. I used to be able to use bluetooth on fedora, but now for some reason it is not working. I don't know what exactly caused it, but now when I try to go into settings and turn the slider on for bluetooth, the slider is still grey and bluetooth wont turn on. Bluetooth has worked fine when I boot to windows. Bluetooth appears in the quick settings as well, but when I click on it it does nothing.

## Relevant outputs

[image]

```
~ ❯ lsusb                                                                     06:24:45 PM
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 005 Device 002: ID 27c6:6594 Shenzhen Goodix Technology Co.,Ltd. Goodix USB2.0 MISC
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 04f2:b70f Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd Integrated Camera
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

```
~ ❯ systemctl status bluetooth                                                06:25:40 PM
● bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled; preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Wed 2022-11-16 18:02:08 EST; 24min ago
       Docs: man:bluetoothd(8)
   Main PID: 3092 (bluetoothd)
     Status: "Running"
      Tasks: 1 (limit: 17701)
     Memory: 1.8M
        CPU: 28ms
     CGroup: /system.slice/bluetooth.service
             └─3092 /usr/libexec/bluetooth/bluetoothd

Nov 16 18:02:08 <name of computer redacted> systemd[1]: Starting bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service...
Nov 16 18:02:08 <name of computer redacted> systemd[3092]: ConfigurationDirectory 'bluetooth' already exists but the mode is different. (File system: 755 ConfigurationDirectoryMode: 555)
Nov 16 18:02:08 <name of computer redacted> bluetoothd[3092]: Bluetooth daemon 5.65
Nov 16 18:02:08 <name of computer redacted> systemd[1]: Started bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service.
Nov 16 18:02:08 <name of computer redacted> bluetoothd[3092]: Starting SDP server
Nov 16 18:02:08 <name of computer redacted> bluetoothd[3092]: Bluetooth management interface 1.22 initialized
```

```
~ ❯ rfkill list all                                                           06:34:34 PM
0: tpacpi_bluetooth_sw: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
2: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
5: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

```
~ ❯ lspci                                                               ✘ 0|1 06:36:12 PM
00:00.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir/Cezanne Root Complex
00:00.2 IOMMU: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir/Cezanne IOMMU
00:01.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
00:02.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
00:02.1 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir/Cezanne PCIe GPP Bridge
00:02.2 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir/Cezanne PCIe GPP Bridge
00:02.3 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir/Cezanne PCIe GPP Bridge
00:02.7 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir/Cezanne PCIe GPP Bridge
00:08.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
00:08.1 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir Internal PCIe GPP Bridge to Bus
00:14.0 SMBus: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH SMBus Controller (rev 51)
00:14.3 ISA bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH LPC Bridge (rev 51)
00:18.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Cezanne Data Fabric; Function 0
00:18.1 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Cezanne Data Fabric; Function 1
00:18.2 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Cezanne Data Fabric; Function 2
00:18.3 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Cezanne Data Fabric; Function 3
00:18.4 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Cezanne Data Fabric; Function 4
00:18.5 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Cezanne Data Fabric; Function 5
00:18.6 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Cezanne Data Fabric; Function 6
00:18.7 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Cezanne Data Fabric; Function 7
01:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: Sandisk Corp WD Black SN750 / PC SN730 NVMe SSD
02:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 0e)
03:00.0 Network controller: Qualcomm QCNFA765 Wireless Network Adapter (rev 01)
04:00.0 USB controller: Renesas Technology Corp. uPD720202 USB 3.0 Host Controller (rev 02)
05:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Cezanne [Radeon Vega Series / Radeon Vega Mobile Series] (rev d1)
05:00.1 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Renoir Radeon High Definition Audio Controller
05:00.2 Encryption controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 10h-1fh) Platform Security Processor
05:00.3 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir/Cezanne USB 3.1
05:00.4 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir/Cezanne USB 3.1
05:00.5 Multimedia controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] ACP/ACP3X/ACP6x Audio Coprocessor (rev 01)
05:00.6 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h/19h HD Audio Controller
```

```
~ ❯ bluetoothctl                                                              06:45:16 PM
Agent registered
[bluetooth]# list
[bluetooth]# power on
No default controller available
[bluetooth]#
```

```
~ ❯ sudo dmesg | egrep -i 'blue|firm'                                         06:44:55 PM
[sudo] password for connor: 
[    0.104249] Spectre V2 : Enabling Restricted Speculation for firmware calls
[    0.265426] ACPI: [Firmware Bug]: BIOS _OSI(Linux) query ignored
[    0.285468] acpi PNP0A08:00: [Firmware Info]: MMCONFIG for domain 0000 [bus 00-3f] only partially covers this bridge
[    0.595185] xhci_hcd 0000:04:00.0: failed to load firmware renesas_usb_fw.mem, fallback to ROM
[    1.182529] psmouse serio1: trackpoint: Elan TrackPoint firmware: 0xa1, buttons: 3/3
[    2.991102] [drm] Loading DMUB firmware via PSP: version=0x0101001F
[    3.010931] [drm] Found VCN firmware Version ENC: 1.17 DEC: 5 VEP: 0 Revision: 2
[    3.010936] amdgpu 0000:05:00.0: amdgpu: Will use PSP to load VCN firmware
[    5.902782] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[    5.902804] NET: Registered PF_BLUETOOTH protocol family
[    5.902806] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[    5.902810] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[    5.902812] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[    5.902817] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[    6.035188] thinkpad_acpi: rfkill switch tpacpi_bluetooth_sw: radio is unblocked
[    6.089221] Bluetooth: hci0: using rampatch file: qca/rampatch_usb_00130200.bin
[    6.089225] Bluetooth: hci0: QCA: patch rome 0x130200 build 0x4610, firmware rome 0x130200 build 0x17f3
[    6.774759] Bluetooth: hci0: using NVM file: qca/nvm_usb_00130200.bin
[    6.807908] Bluetooth: hci0: HCI Enhanced Setup Synchronous Connection command is advertised, but not supported.
[    6.991541] Bluetooth: hci0: unexpected cc 0x2060 length: 1 < 7
[    6.991549] Bluetooth: hci0: Opcode 0x2060 failed: -38
[    9.023413] Bluetooth: hci0: command tx timeout
[   54.397852] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[   54.397856] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[   54.397860] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[   74.481545] Bluetooth: hci0: using rampatch file: qca/rampatch_usb_00130200.bin
[   74.481548] Bluetooth: hci0: QCA: patch rome 0x130200 build 0x4610, firmware rome 0x130200 build 0x17f3
[   75.170703] Bluetooth: hci0: using NVM file: qca/nvm_usb_00130200.bin
[   75.203046] Bluetooth: hci0: HCI Enhanced Setup Synchronous Connection command is advertised, but not supported.
[   75.386913] Bluetooth: hci0: unexpected cc 0x2060 length: 1 < 7
[   75.386993] Bluetooth: hci0: Opcode 0x2060 failed: -38
[   77.441514] Bluetooth: hci0: command tx timeout
[ 1301.808639] Bluetooth: hci0: using rampatch file: qca/rampatch_usb_00130200.bin
[ 1301.808644] Bluetooth: hci0: QCA: patch rome 0x130200 build 0x4610, firmware rome 0x130200 build 0x17f3
[ 1302.504022] Bluetooth: hci0: using NVM file: qca/nvm_usb_00130200.bin
[ 1302.536483] Bluetooth: hci0: HCI Enhanced Setup Synchronous Connection command is advertised, but not supported.
[ 1302.719734] Bluetooth: hci0: unexpected cc 0x2060 length: 1 < 7
[ 1302.719797] Bluetooth: hci0: Opcode 0x2060 failed: -38
[ 1304.769313] Bluetooth: hci0: command tx timeout
[ 2001.700180] Bluetooth: hci0: using rampatch file: qca/rampatch_usb_00130200.bin
[ 2001.700185] Bluetooth: hci0: QCA: patch rome 0x130200 build 0x4610, firmware rome 0x130200 build 0x17f3
[ 2002.396036] Bluetooth: hci0: using NVM file: qca/nvm_usb_00130200.bin
[ 2002.428669] Bluetooth: hci0: HCI Enhanced Setup Synchronous Connection command is advertised, but not supported.
[ 2002.851478] Bluetooth: hci0: unexpected cc 0x2060 length: 1 < 7
[ 2002.851524] Bluetooth: hci0: Opcode 0x2060 failed: -38
[ 2004.873481] Bluetooth: hci0: command tx timeout
```

```
~ ❯ sudo btmgmt                                                                                                                                                                                                                    06:51:25 PM
[sudo] password for connor: 
[mgmt]# extinfo
Extended index list with 0 items

[mgmt]#
```

```
~ ❯ lsmod | grep btusb                                                                                                                                                                                                      1m 19s 06:55:20 PM
btusb                  65536  0
btrtl                  28672  1 btusb
btbcm                  24576  1 btusb
btintel                49152  1 btusb
btmtk                  16384  1 btusb
bluetooth             880640  15 btrtl,btmtk,btintel,btbcm,bnep,btusb
~ ❯
```

## Other Notes

I have also tried restarting the bluetooth service, disabling it and starting it manually after reboot. I made sure secure boot is disabled and fast startup was disabled in windows control panel settings, which was suggested by another forum. I blocked and unblocked bluetooth with `sudo rfkill block bluetooth && sudo rfkill unblock bluetooth`. If any additional information is needed, please let me know.

Comment: You might get a faster answer by making the Overview or "Problem" section at the time an abbreviated version of the problem. Right now Overview is quite a lot of text, like a wall. It's hard to quickly parse, which may make some not continue to read and understand your problem.

Comment: Thank you for the insight. However, I have talked to my friend about the issue and we have found the issue. I will make an edit to the post.

Comment: Please remove your edit about your solution and add the solution and how you solved it to this question as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue seems to be that the network card I was using (Qualcomm) does not work right out of the box for Linux (at least not for Bluetooth - WiFi was working). I did some searching to see if I could find a driver for the Qualcomm card but couldn't find anything.

My solution was to purchase an Intel card for about 20 USD, which has support for Linux right out of the box. After installing the card, Bluetooth worked on both Windows 11 and Fedora 37. It was a very easy installation for my ThinkPad.

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue that seems to be prevalent on most Linux Distros, as far as I've seen. I've yet to find a "fix" for it that actually works. I've been having the same problem myself.

You'll find a number of other questions revolving around this issue.

It generally boils down to "The OS can see it's there (see "lsmod") but doesn't allow it to actually function in any way."

Recommendations from around include:

- run "rfkill unblock (your bluetooth device)" (run "rfkill list" to show devices, although chances are the bluetooth dev won't show...)
- try installing drivers
- Run "systemctl enable bluetooth"
- Run "service bluetooth enable"

And a number of others.

I've tried as many as I can find, but none of them have worked for me.

Maybe you'll have better luck.
If you find any others that do work, let me know.

Comment: I've given up on Linux, been using ubuntu & fedora since 2007 on & off, but now bcoz of work I use it on an office laptop daily, this OS is not useable as a PC. I'll switch forever as soon I can afford to get a Mac.

Comment: It's actually more user friendly than you think. It's just very picky about who its friends are :)

Comment: I don't see any other tag for other OS with this many issues. Friends with an os, not even funny. Linus says he doesn't like some Linux distro bcoz he feel those are difficult to work with. Now thats funny isn't it

Comment: Some people find Linux easy to get the hang of, some find it relatively intuitive. But that's an issue that's applicable to most OS's.